# Type TextBox Not Found

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying to create form in Xamarin and use a TextBox. When I compile the code I get the following error.

```
Type TextBox not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms
```

I haven't been able to find any similar issues, and this is my first Xamarin program so I'm not sure where to go from here. Is the xmlns link outdated and just not include TextBoxes?

### MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <TextBox Width="500" Header="Email" 
            PlaceholderText="Enter registered email." />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: There isn't a TextBox control in Xamarin.Forms. I think you're looking for either an `Entry` or an `Editor`. A list of the built-in controls can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/views).

Comment: @Nick Oh man thank you so much. I was pulling my hair out. I just realized that I clicked on the wrong Microsoft documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Email" />
        <Entry WidthRequest="500" Placeholder="Enter registered email" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```